# Simple hangman game number of tries doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I follow this tutorial from a book and I try to add in the end if the guess is not right guessesNr--. In the beginning I set up this variable to 4.

Right now my guessesNr-- reduce to many numbers once so I don't know how to fix it reduce only one try from 4, until guessesNr < 0. 
Can someone please tell me how to do it?

```js
var words = [
 "javascript",
 "monkey",
 "amazing",
 "pancake"
 ];

var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];

//create an empty array called answerArray and fill it 
//with underscores (_) to match the number
//of letters in the word
var answerArray = [];

for( var i=0; i < word.length; i++) {
 answerArray[i] = "_";
}

//every time the player guesses a
//correct letter, this value will 
//be decremented (reduced) by 1
var remainingLetters = word.length;
var guessesNr = 4;
while((remainingLetters > 0) && (guessesNr > 0)) {
 // Show the player their progress
 alert("The word is from " + word.length + " letters " + answerArray.join(" "));
 // Take input from player
 var guess = prompt("Guess a letter");

 // if the player clicks the Cancel button, then guess will be null
 if(guess===null) {
  // break to exit the loop
  break;
  //ensuring that guess is exactly one letter
 } else if(guess.length !== 1) {
  alert("Please enter a single letter!");
 } else {
  for(var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
   if(word[j] === guess) {
    // sets the element at index j, from word, 
    // of answerArray to guess
                answerArray[j] = guess;
    remainingLetters--;
   
   } else { 
    //guessesNr--;
    //console.log("guessesNr", guessesNr);
   }
  }
 }
 
}

//alert(answerArray.join(" "));
alert("Great job! The answer was " + word);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="hangman-test1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to decrement once you know they have put in a legitimate guess:

```
        var isHit = false;
        for(var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
            if(word[j] === guess) {
                // sets the element at index j, from word, 
                // of answerArray to guess
                remainingLetters--;
                isHit = true;
            }
        }
        if (!isHit) {
            guessesNr--;
        }
```

Comment: I did this but even I put the right letter still does -- like I put the wrong letter. Can you check please in my code?

Comment: Ok. I've edited the solution to only decrement if they didn't get any matches.

Answer (score 0):

`guessesNr` is decremented in the `for` loop so it goes down by 1 for each letter in the word. You need to move the `guessesNr--` outside the loop.

I haven't checked for other issues.